# No endpoint listening after application update

Tags: c#, wcf

We have a C#.NET Windows application that consumes a WCF service. The application receives updates through the web service. The `.exe` and `.dll` files are downloaded and the old ones are renamed as `library.dll.old`. The next time the application is started up, the updated files are used and the old ones removed. The `app.config` file does not get overwritten.

When the application starts up again any attempts to communicate with the web-service returns the exception:

> "No endpoint listening that could accept the message... often caused by incorrect address or soap action".

The only fix is to disable and re-enable the network adapter after which everything is back to normal and communication is resumed.

Any ideas?
TIA

Comment: Is the WCF service self-hosted on the local machine?

Comment: The WCF service is hosted in IIS on a machine on a different VLAN within the company network. It is public facing.